# Calculate view measure before display it

Tags: android, view, size, measure

I am trying to add views to LinearLayout dynamically as much as it possible (depending on screen width).

I do this before the LinearLayout displays on screen.

My LinearLayout:

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center" 
    android:background="#666"/>
```

My view to display in LinearLayout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:paddingLeft="10dp" 
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:background="#999">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:src="@drawable/no_photo"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

I add views to layout:

```
int allItems = 50;
int currentItem = 0;
while(currentItem < allItems)
{
    FrameLayout view = (FrameLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fl, null);

    linearLayout.addView(view);

    if (linearLayout.getMeasuredWidth() >= this.getWidth())
    {
        linearLayout.removeView(view);
        break;
    }
}
```

but linearLayout.getMeasuredWidth() and this.getWidth() is 0;

I know, that i must use View.measure method to calculate view size before it became visible, but i don't know where and how it use.

Comment: Possible dupe of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142090/how-do-you-to-retrieve-dimensions-of-a-view-getheight-and-getwidth-always-r/4406090#4406090

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9498762/dynamically-adding-views-to-horizontal-linearlayout-goes-out-of-the-screen

Comment: "android:background="#666"" - I see you are using the magic number just like I do

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Edit your code as below :

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
int maxWidth = display.getWidth();
int widthSoFar=0;

int allItems = 50;
int currentItem = 0;

while(currentItem < allItems) {
  FrameLayout view = (FrameLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fl, null);

  linearLayout.addView(view);

  view .measure(0, 0);
  widthSoFar = widthSoFar + view.getMeasuredWidth();


  if (widthSoFar >= maxWidth) {
    linearLayout.removeView(view);
    break;
  }
}
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: But if my parent view not take full screen width?

Comment: Then you can put your parent view width inside maxWidth by calling parentView.getMeasureWidth(). which is your parent view here?

Comment: 1) get screen width; 2) add my view to layout 3) measure layout width 4) check if layout measured width more than screen width 5) if true remove last added view

Comment: @KorniltsevAnatoly  Check it out here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937238/android-view-measureint-int-always-wants-to-be-0-0

Comment: you are measuring each view that is being added. And you ignore margins, weights, layout params btw. Isn't there a generic way to just measure the linearlayout?